# Java - Applying a vector method on a matrix row or column

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

I'm writing a method that does something to a vector (1-dimensional array). I want to apply it to rows and columns of a matrix (2-dimensional array: array of rows, each row is an array). I'd like to know the best approach to do so.

The vector method may take additional parameters. It could, for example, implement a sorting algorithm (mine doesn't, but it's complicated enough).

Now, if `matrix` is a matrix and I want to use the method on the 4th row, I simply plug `matrix[3]` into the method, so when the method accesses `a[n]`, it will end up accessing `matrix[3][n]`. But it's not so simple to apply it onto a column, because whenever the method accesses `a[n]` I would want it to access `matrix[n][7]` (in case of 8th column).

I have in the past tried to apply a vector method to access `list[index[n]]` (`list` and `index` are vectors) whenever the method accessed `a[n]`. I used the copying way then (no 1. below).

Ways I've thought of (none elegant):

1. Create a vector, copy the contents of a column into the vector, apply the method, then copy the contents of the vector back into the column of the matrix (and dispose of the vector / reuse it for application on another column later).
2. Duplicate the method, one working with `a[n]`, where `a` is a vector parameter, and one working with `a[n][m]`, where `a` is a matrix parameter and `m` is an int parameter.
3. Design the method so it either works with a vector or with a matrix column, but then the working of the method will be complicated by allowing for 2 cases each time an element is accessed.
4. Maybe the parameter can be a function `f` (however implemented) so the method uses `f(n)`? Then for a vector `vector`, `f` given is such that `f(n)` returns (the reference to) `vector[n]`. For a row of matrix `matrix`, `f(n)` returns `matrix[row][n]` and for a column `f(n)` returns `matrix[n][column]`

Answer (score 1):

Define an abstraction (assuming your matrix contains integers):

```
public interface IntVector {
    public int size();
    public int get(int index);
    public void set(int index, int value);
}
```

Change your algrithm so that it uses an IntVector rather than an array.

Then define two implementations:

```
public class RowVector implements IntVector {

    private final int[] row;

    public RowVector(int[] row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return row.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
        return row[index];
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, int value) {
        row[index] = value;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ColumnVector implements IntVector {
    private final int[][] matrix;
    private final int column;

    public ColumnVector(int[][] matrix, int column) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return matrix.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
        return matrix[index][this.column];
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, int value) {
        matrix[index][this.column] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Taking a proper advantage of OOP. I don't think that way, my programs are old thinking forced into OOP, haha. When the method is used on RowVector, is it (almost) as efficient as if written directly for a 1D array?

Comment: I would guess that it is as efficient, because the JIT will probably inline the method.